# App to identify codecs in video files

Tags: windows-xp, video, audio, codec

I am looking for an app that will identify audio and video codecs in a given AVI or MP4 or what have you.

Does something like that exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/Download) for that kind of thing.

Answer (score 5):

The [GSpot Codec Information Appliance](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/) is great for identifying codecs and containers of just about any file.  The interface isn't great but it can be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

[Mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) can dump data about a videofile.

There is a Windows version of it and you could parse its output.

Answer (score -1):

er... Sorry if I give a too obvious answer... There's a quick way to see basic info, very basic, for this. In windows, just right click on the file, Properties, "Summary" tab, then hit button "advanced". Again, sorry if is too obvious to mention this.